# How to generate Tests in tests/ directory in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

PhpStorm has some sort of weird behaviour that is driving me crazy. I've got my project setup to have a `source` and a `test` directory. The `source` directory should be for productive code, while the `test` directory should contain all the phpunit tests.

In those directories, the folder structure is mirrored - if I have a class `\foo\Bar`, 
then there is
`src/foo/Bar.php` and `test/foo/BarTest.php`.

I've marked `src/` and `test/` as source and test directory in PhpStorm, however, every time I want to create a new test suite for a class, PhpStorm defaults to put the test class into the `src/` directory next to the class under test.

It's possible to change that, however it get's more annoying when that same directory in `test/` does not exist yet. Instead of creating it, PhpStorm will just reject to create that test suite for me.

Maybe I am misunderstanding the concept behind test management in PhpStorm quite a bit - because it just can't be that bad user experience.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or something that I can configure to make the situation less painful?

Comment: No -- nothing wrong. It just does not work this way -- devs coded it to behave in a way it is right now. There are tickets about changing such behaviour to the same as you described/desired .. but so far it does not look like it's in their priority list...

Comment: I click generate test in test directory then i choose class and proper namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing **nothing** wrong. It just does not work this way -- devs coded it to behave in a way it is right now.

Originally IDE used PHPUnit's ability to generate test classes (back then such functionality was part of actual PHPUnit). Then PHPUnit creator(s) have moved this functionality into separate package (`phpunit-skelgen`) .. and you had to install it manually/separately. Then devs decided to [drop phpunit-skelgen support completely](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16054#comment=27-430169) and implemented current implementation (which is also more in line with similar routines in other IDEs built on IDEA platform/technologies supported by those IDEs).

There are quite few tickets about changing such behaviour to the same as you described/desired .. but so far it does not look like it's in their priority list...

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2850
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24358
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21890

Subscribe to those tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

Answer (score 2):

As of release 2016.3 PHPStorm now takes places tests in the specified tests directory, providing exactly what you ask for in your question.

Comment: Do you know if this functionality was reverted? I've attempted this with 2017.2 and I get the same result as OP.

Comment: Same for me, but it changes directory to correct one when you change namespace to reflect your tests directory in 'Create New Test...' popup. 
IIRC it worked in early 2017 version, but stopped after upgrade.